# WPF Main Menu with other controls

Tags: wpf, menu

I am quite new to WPF and this might be a trivial question. What I want is to have the main menu with e.g. File, Edit, View etc, and to have a couple of controls in the window e.g few TextBoxes, Buttons, ListBoxes etc. How should I structure my XAML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--
        MENU
    -->
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="File"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Edit"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Help"/>
    </Menu>

    <!--
          APP CONTENT
    -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="20">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="Enter text here" Height="20"/>
        <Button Content="Click me" Height="20" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

See http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thanks!